# How to rescue this task?

Tags: c#, console-application

I wonder how to do or write a code that it will print out no one got 20 points and it has to write a number of line. Everything works except `if (is20 == false)`. How to fix it?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[,] points = new double[50, 5];
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    points[k, j] = r.NextDouble() * 5 + 15.5;
                    if (points[k, j] > 20) points[k, j] = 20;
                    Console.Write("{0:f1}", points[k, j]);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            bestEstimated(points);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void bestEstimated(double[,] points)
        {
            bool is20 = false;
            for (int line = 0; line < 50; line++)
            {    
                for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
                {
                    if (points[line, column] == 20)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("20 points got: " + line + " competitor");
                        is20 = true;
                        break;
                    }    
                }    
            }

            if (is20 == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No one got 20 points: ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line number should that be? As no one reached 20 points so do you want to write? `Console.WriteLine("No one got 20 points: Lines: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 .... 47, 48, 49, 50");` ?!?

Comment: Exactly, not all lines, but just these one which do not include 20 points.

Comment: A task includes two dimensional table with fifty lines. In each line there are points from 15.5 to 20.0.

Comment: Try a code and you will see what I am talking about

Comment: But your code doesnt reflect what you are saying, you are breaking on the first first hit and say `is20 = true` so if a single one has 20 points you dont print the below text. Also your text doesnt reflect what you want it says `No one got 20 points` this means 0 people got 20 points, what you are saying is more like `Those lines didnt get 20 points: [lines]`

Comment: What I want is, first part of task I have to do that it will print me out which competitors got 20 points, this is a number of line and the other part of task is that application must print out which lines do not include 20 points. Line numbers are like competitors.

Comment: I did the first part, but the second one I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `is20=false` in inner loop in else part and check it inside outer loop after inner loop.

```
public static void bestEstimated(double[,] points)
    {
        bool is20 = false;
        for (int line = 0; line < 10; line++)
        {

            for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
            {
                if (points[line, column] == 20)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("20 points got: " + line + " competitor");
                    is20 = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    is20=false;
                }

            }
            if (!is20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("20 points not got: " + line + " competitor");
            }

        }
        if(is20 == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No one got 20 points: ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you ignore the `Console.WriteLine("No one got 20 points: ");` part yes it "works"

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess from your comments below your question:

```
public static void bestEstimated(double[,] points)
{
    var not20Points = new List<int>();
    for (int line = 0; line < 50; line++)
    {    
        bool is20 = false;
        for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
        {
            if (points[line, column] == 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("20 points got: " + line + " competitor");
                is20 = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (is20 == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("competitor" + line + " didnt get 20 points"); //also can print it here if ya want...
            not20Points.Add(line);
        }
    }

    if (not20Points.Count == 50)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No one got 20 points");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Those lines did get 20 points: " + string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Except(not20Points)));
        Console.WriteLine("Those lines didnt get 20 points: " + string.Join(",", not20Points));
    }
}
```

(Updated my version, to only print stuff if atleast one column has 20 points)

Comment: I do not want a list of number. i want that it will be written like it is for "20 points got: "

Comment: You arent getting a list of number, the list of number is just there to tract the lines, with the code you will receive the text `Those lines didnt get 20 points: 1, 5, 7, 9, 25` if 1, 5, 7, 9, 25 dont have 20 points

Comment: @A.Maksimović - updated my answer to reflect your need to print the result for each individual line - also added a positive summary at the end